# How can I encapsulate svelte app within iframe of svelte app?

Tags: iframe, media-queries, svelte

A svelte app targeted for mobile will be emulated online (a mobile drawing with the actual app rendered inside). Because of media queries (which don't work since the app is the whole page and not just the mobile drawing content), my best solution would be that the app should be inside of an iframe.

Is there a way of doing that without actually writing another svelte app that encapsulates the former? Since it will bundle everything together. I could deal with sapper settings to control that, but it seems a little messy to me. As is distorting CSS to emulate media queries, toggling all back when released to production target.

I would then be running two diferent sapper CLI's dev servers, package.json's, git repos, etc. Also have to think about deploy, regarding two public/dist folders and their paths/routes.

Any other thoughts?

EDIT: to be more clear, I have essentially 4 options:

1 - adapt CSS without media queries and vh/vw units (way to hard and sometimes maybe impossible)

2 - emulator as component (but where would iframe src point to?)

3 - set two rollup outputs, maybe app is a hydratable component. Iframe would point to output 2 (how to coordinate that? index1 vs index2? same public folder with 2 rendered parts of an app)

4 - two independent apps, the whole thing  (how to deploy? two webservers could do, but ideally it should become one final app)

Hope it is clearer

Answer (score 4):

You can use just select the target to be iframe body. More info about how to create a svelte component https://svelte.dev/docs#Client-side_component_API

```
import App from './App.svelte';

const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.onload = (ev) => {
    const app = new App({
        target: iframe.contentWindow.document.body,
        props: {
            name: 'world'
        }
    });
};
document.body.append(iframe);
```

Comment: its working fine but css aren't loading

Answer (score 1):

Building on the reply by Doua Beri, you can just copy the documents head to the iframe, this will make your css work, one problem you might encounter is that if your app uses stores they will be shared with the main app

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.head.replaceWith(document.head.cloneNode(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

if I got you right.

1. how about packing into a scrollable div?
2. your svelte app is packaged into a bundle.js. Rename index.html to sth.html and then iframe src=sth.html in the new index.html

Comment: yes, for 1 the problem are media queries (works for the inner app when is the entire page, but fails when inside the div), and in 2 I need 2 index.html, one for emulator and another for the app itself. I could rename, but how to configure everything?

Comment: in your case, probably opening local html with iframe, targeted to correct index.html, will be the solution. But this already looks a bit crutchy. So I recommend to refactor css`s